# Android Emulator Wifi limited connection

Tags: android, android-emulator

Wifi на android симуляторе перестал работать из-за какого-то лимита. Кто-нибудь знает как выключить этот лимит?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже пытался делать wipe data в avd manager

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `Windows` делается так:

1. Откройте Центр управления сетями и общим доступом и щелкните текущее
   соединение.
2. Щелкните Свойства
3. Дважды щелкните Интернет-протокол версии 4 (TCP / IPv4)
4. Установите предпочтительный и альтернативный DNS-серверы как (например):

   ```
   8.8.8.8
   8.8.4.4
   ```

[Вот первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet) и подобные обсуждения: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495920/android-emulator-wifi-connected-no-internet), [статья](https://medium.com/@cafonsomota/android-emulator-when-theres-no-connection-to-the-internet-129e8b63b7ce)